# JavaScript submit enable on keyup

Tags: javascript, button, submit

My submit button becomes disabled but won't go back to being enabled. What's wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <form method="post" action="timer.html">
        <p><input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username" id='userNameCheck' onkeyup="checkUserName()"></p>
        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" id="mySubmit"></p>
     </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("mySubmit").disabled = true;
    function checkUserName() {
        var userNames = document.getElementById("userNameCheck");
        if(userNames === 'andrius'){
            document.getElementById("mySubmit").disabled = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Change your if statement to compare the input value: `if(userNames.value=='andrius')` I would also recommend having `}else{` in your statement other wise once the submit button is changed you have nothing to change it again.

Comment: You should provide proper documented details along with the questions. This is a very generic question and there is no requirement mentioned here except enable and disable the button. You should write when to enable and disable the button.

Comment: @AnkitTanna I don't think this question needs much explaining. I can see what the OP is trying to achieve just from reading the javascript. `if(userNames === 'andrius')` makes it pretty obvious the OP wants to enable the submit button if the userNameCheck input value = to andrius.

Comment: Thats fine @NewToJS This is just a small snippet. Initially I was not able to figure out when does he want the button to be enabled. Anyway, he should use onchange and then bind the onkeyup event because I can continuously press a escape button and call this function several times.

Answer (score 0):

> your code has some problems

```
<input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username"  id='userNameCheck' onkeyup="checkUserName()" disabled= "disabled">
```

> your js code should look like this

```
function checkUserName() {
    var userNames = document.getElementById("userNameCheck").value;
    alert(userNames);
    if(userNames === 'andrius'){
        alert("true");
        document.getElementById("mySubmit").disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Your error was you did not get the username field value. It was returned as html object. This code will work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have many mistakes,
Mistake 1:
You are trying to disable the button before the DOM loads the button on the webpage, this will throw error.

```
document.getElementById("mySubmit").disabled = true;
```

This must be kept inside a function which is called onload.

Mistake 2:

```
 var userNames = document.getElementById("userNameCheck");
```

Above line doesn't pass the value to the variable,

Complete Working Solution :
Copy-Paste this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function onLoad()
 {
  document.getElementById("mySubmit").disabled = true;
 }
 function checkUserName() {
         var userNames = document.getElementById("userNameCheck").value;
         if(userNames === 'andrius'){
             document.getElementById("mySubmit").disabled = false;
         }
     }
    </script>
```

Comment: Since jQuery is not tagged in this question, I would recommend clearly pointing out the use of jQuery.

Comment: @NewToJS : Yeah..! Fine .. Not at all a big deal. I have updated the answer, WITHOUT JQUERY. And I don't think everyone out here follows the tag. I far as I know, smart solutions are accepted.

Comment: No need to be so defensive. Tags are there for a reason and jQuery might no be available to the OP for some reason. I don't see anything wrong about posting a jQuery solution as long as you have pointed out the use of jQuery. Accepting answers has nothing to do with being the smartest answer. It's the most useful answer, with good detail and explanation to help the OP understand the source code and reason(s) for it not functioning as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the disabled attribute to your submit button. `disabled="disabled"` I have also added the value property to your `userNames` variable to compare the value within your if statement. As recommended in my comment, i have added  `else` into your if statement to disable the button if the input changes from andrius. If the user types andrius and then removes it, your submit button will not be disabled as your if statement has enabled it.

```js
    function checkUserName() {
        var userNames = document.getElementById("userNameCheck");
        var SubBtn=document.getElementById("mySubmit");
        if(userNames.value === 'andrius'){
            SubBtn.disabled=false;
        }else{
         SubBtn.disabled=true;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <form method="post" action="timer.html">
        <p><input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username" id='userNameCheck' onkeyup="checkUserName()"/></p>
        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" id="mySubmit" disabled="disabled"/></p>
     </form>
</div>
```

If you have any questions, please leave a comment and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I found problem my self, but thank you all for information.
The problem was:
I forgot to put .value l